# How do I set a value to null based on a second value in same row in SQL?

Tags: sql, null

If I have the following data:

```
    ID        weight         height       bmi
    1         200              70          12 
    1         200                          12
```

I want to set the BMI to null where there is no height.
I don't want to set the whole column to null just the rows where height is null
My desired output would be:

```
   ID        weight          height       bmi
   1          200              70          12
   1          200
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to change the data, use a `case` expression:

```
select id, weight, height,
       (case when height is not null then bmi end) as bmi
from t;
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following update:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET bmi = NULL
WHERE height IS NULL;
```